# created Tab bar and side menu Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I created tab bar and side menu using Sw reveal programmatically but after implementing all process i cant able to view side menu and my tab bar also disappeared...i don't know how to alloc them pleas help me out

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.tabBarController =[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

   //Initialize View controller and speciality
    UIViewController *viewcontroller1=[[HomeView alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller2=[[Speciality alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller3=[[Activity alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller4 =[[Notification alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller5 =[[Profile alloc]init];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewcontroller1,viewcontroller2,viewcontroller3,viewcontroller4,viewcontroller5, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController =self.tabBarController;
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.376 green:0.729 blue:0.318 alpha:1.000];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    HomeView *frontViewController = [[HomeView alloc] init];
    RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
    UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];
    SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
    mainRevealController.delegate = self;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set your `window.rootViewController` two times. And it seems the second time you assign `nil` to it, as I can't see any initialization/assignement to `self.viewController`.

Comment: i created tab bar and side menu in one view controller how to call them in one viewcontroller

Comment: Use a container view controller. See "Implementing a Container View Controller" at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/.